# Why could a session_end event run other than the timeout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am using .net 3.5 and I assigned the sessionstate element a timeout property of 30 minutes. To my surprise the session_end event sometimes runs even when there have not been 30 minutes of inactivity, and I have not declared session.Abandon() anywhere in my code.

I can't find much info about this occurring on the internet, can you help me out?

Comment: There are many variables why the session_end is triggered. Where is the site hosted? Maybe the  machine is set to go idle in less than 30 mins if there is no activity...

Comment: Read also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695403/asp-net-session-ending-abruptly